# ConTeXt: String manipulation

Tags: context, strings

The [string manipulation](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/String_manipulation) wiki page has an example that does not compile successfully. There must be some syntax to place before and after this code, but I cannot find any details about this in the documentation. The snippet is:

```
\starttext
    str = "Luxury Yacht"

    rep = {
        [1] = { "Luxury", "Throatwobbler"   },
        [2] = { "Yacht",  "Mangrove"        },
    }

    print("My name is spelled “" .. str .. "”, but it's pronounced “" .. lpeg.replacer(rep):match(str) .. "”.")

\stoptext
```

- How can I use this feature in my document?
- Can I place all of the text from my document inside `print()` to perform some changes to all of the text? E.g., to replace all occurrences of "apple" with "fruit" in the document?

I am particularly interested in using the [lpeg.replacer(table)](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/String_manipulation#lpeg.replacer.28table.29) feature.

Comment: I did not see `\directlua` in the manual. I have tried placing `\directlua{}` around the code, but this is an "Undefined control sequence."

Comment: In ConTeXt, the `\directlua` primitive is wrapped up as `\ctxlua`.

Comment: @Village: See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX for a basic overview of going back and forth between lua and tex.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702776/2148

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things wrong here. First, you need to 'escape to Lua', which could be done using the `\directlua` primitive but for which there are 'higher level' wrappers: `\ctxlua{...}` or `\startluacode ... \stopluacode` . Secondly, you need to 'print' your output to TeX, which can be done using `tex.print(...)` or `context(...)`; the latter also calls `string.format`, so you can use printf style arguments.

```
\starttext
  \startluacode
    local str = "Luxury Yacht"

    local rep = {
        [1] = { "Luxury", "Throatwobbler"   },
        [2] = { "Yacht",  "Mangrove"        },
    }
    context("My name is spelled “%s”, but it's pronounced “%s”.", str, lpeg.replacer(rep):match(str))
  \stopluacode

\stoptext
```

Comment: Does it need any special instructions to compile? With `texexec file.tex` it does not create a file, but I could not find any errors.

Comment: @Village You need ConTeXt Mark IV: `context file.tex`.

Comment: @JosephWright: I edited the answer to use `context(...)` and `printf` style arguments, which I think are easier to read than string concatenation.

Comment: @Aditya I know the basics for ConTeXt and Lua, so am very happy to have things improved. I assume that the `context()` function is ConTeXt-only. [What is 'easier to read' depends on whether you are used to a `printf`-style approach :-)]

Answer (score 1):

```
\starttext
  \def\LuaTest#1#2{\directlua{
    str = "#1 #2"
    rep = {
        [1] = { "Luxury", "Throatwobbler"   },
        [2] = { "Yacht",  "Mangrove"        },
    }
    tex.print("My name is spelled “" .. str .. "”, but it's pronounced “" .. lpeg.replacer(rep):match(str) .. "”.")}}

\LuaTest{Luxury}{Yacht}
\stoptext
```

Comment: If you want to define a TeX macro, the usual practice is to define a lua function, say `userdata.annouce_name(str)` and then use `\def\LuaTest#1#2{\ctxlua{userdata.annouce_name("#1 #2")}`

Comment: that's true in general if one has more than one TeX macro with Lua functions to define