# ConTeXt: Substitute em-dash for double-hyphens

Tags: luatex, punctuation, context-mkiv, ampersand

## Background

I am trying to [substitute](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) an em-dash for double-hyphens (`--`) whenever they occur in user-generated text. The fonts that I am using ([Chivo](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Chivo) and [Gentium Basic](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Gentium+Basic)) result in double-hyphens added to the document, rather than `\emdash{}` (—).

## Problem

The substitution code resembles:

```
\def\SubEmdash#1{%
  \ctxlua{context(string.gsub("#1", "[-][-]", "\\emdash{}"))}
}

\starttext
  \SubEmdash{Escaping ampersands -- \& -- is troublesome.}
\stoptext
```

This fails for strings that contain ampersands.

## Question

An answer to either of these questions would be tremendously helpful:

- How do you force `--` to produce em-dashes throughout the text, regardless of font?
- How would you escape user-generated text so that the `\SubEmdash` macro never fails?

## Related

The following answers also cannot handle ampersands in parameterized text:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41363/2148
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43411/2148
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43376/2148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to [font features](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Featuresets) being disabled by default. Enable font features as follows:

```
\starttypescript [serif] [ContentBody]
  \definefontsynonym [Serif] [name:librebaskervilleregular] [features=default]
\stoptypescript

\definetypeface[ContentFont] [rm] [serif] [ContentBody] [default]
\usetypescript[ContentFont] [ec]
\setupbodyfont[ContentFont]
```

This should automatically output curly quotes, elongated dashes, and ligatures.