# ConTeXt: Escape hash symbols for use with lpeg replacer

Tags: symbols, context, strings, lua

## Background

Looking to perform a text substitution on arbitrary strings. In the code snippet, the value `#a.m. #p.m.` value comes from a document. More specifically, the input is an XML document generated from Markdown. The XML document resembles:

```
<p>See <a class="href" data-type="tbl" href="#ref"/> for details.</p>
```

The `#ref` is proving to be problematic.

### System

ConTeXt version: 2023.09.26 18:19

## Code

Minimal example to show the problem:

```tex
\startluacode
userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.TextReplacements = {}

local function TextReplacement( text )
  text = string.gsub( text, "#", "\\#" )
  local replaced = lpeg.replacer( userdata.TextReplacements ):match( text )
  context( replaced )
end

interfaces.implement {
  name      = "TextReplacement",
  arguments = { "string" },
  public    = true,
  actions   = TextReplacement,
}
\stopluacode

\startluacode
userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.TextReplacements = {
  [1] = { "a.m.", "\\cap{am}" },
  [2] = { "p.m.", "\\cap{pm}" },
}
\stopluacode

\starttext
  \TextReplacement{#a.m. #p.m.}
\stoptext
```

### Details

An additional detail is that the `#ref` value is being read into ConTeXt from the anchor's link and looked up as follows:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{a[@class='href']}{xml:anchorhref}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:anchorhref
  Xref = \xmlatt{#1}{data-type}-\xmlatt{#1}{href}
\stopxmlsetups
```

The `anchorhref` is executed from inside an `xml:p` setup, shown here:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \xmldoifnotselfempty{#1}{%
    \ignorespaces
    \expandafter\TextReplacement{\xmlflush{#1}}
    \removeunwantedspaces
  }
  \par
\stopxmlsetups
```

That call to `\TextReplacement` doesn't work because of the `#` symbol.

## Problem

The [wiki suggests](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/String_manipulation#lpeg.replacer.28table.29) using `lpeg.replacer( ... ):match( ... )`, but that produces a compile error.

By adding a call to `string.gsub`, the compile error goes away, but the output produces double hash symbols:

`##AM ##PM`

## Question

How do you escape the hash symbol and any others that may cause a failure with the string replacement such that no double-hashes are output?

## Related

- [Replacing # characters with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149492/2148)
- [ConTeXt: String manipulation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41359/2148)
- [Which symbols need to be escaped in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48933/2148)
- ["escape" the hash symbol in a macro argument?](https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/RLcPgYQP/is-it-possible-to-escape-the-hash-symbol-in-a-macro-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to be in contact with Hans while reading this question. He first mentioned

```
\starttext
   \catcode`#=11
   \TextReplacement{#a.m. #p.m.}
\stoptext
```

but that might show problems when loading modules and so on. Then he explained that in lmtx we can use

```
text = string.gsub( text, "#", "#H" )
```

The `#H` is a hash escape.

```
\starttext
   #Ha.m. #Hp.m.
\stoptext
```

Gives

[image: ampm]

You can read about that and many more nice new things in [lowlevel-macros.pdf](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/lowlevel-macros.pdf) in your distribution.

He then also mentioned that compiling the replacer each time is not efficient (you probably don't run on a web service, so that might not be a problem), so you better do something like

```
local replacer = lpeg.replacer( userdata.TextReplacements )

local function TextReplacement( text )
   text = string.gsub( text, "#", "#H" )
   context(replacer:match(text))
end
```

I don't want to gain any reputation from this, so I make it a Community wiki.

Comment: "compiling the replacer each time is not efficient" -- moving the replacer shaves between 0.1 and 0.5 seconds off the ~30 second build.

Comment: Indeed, but I guess it all adds up. May I ask how long (how many pages) your document is?

Comment: 262 pages at present. The bottlenecks are probably the larger images and the code that draws hexagonal grids of random complexity and size, reminiscent of neural networks. My plan is to generate each book per person, so even 0.5 seconds helps.

Answer (score 1):

> such that no double-substitutions are performed?

There's not really a double-substitution occurring; the hash symbol just appears twice as far as the Lua processor is concerned. The following document

```tex
\startluacode
    interfaces.implement {
        name      = "test",
        arguments = { "string" },
        public    = true,
        actions   = function(str)
            print("START OUTPUT")
            print(str)
            print("STOP OUTPUT")
        end
    }
\stopluacode

\test{#a}
```

gives this as its output:

```
START OUTPUT
##a
STOP OUTPUT
```

so instead of

```lua
text:gsub("#", ...)
```

you'll need to write

```lua
text:gsub("##", ...)
```

> How do you escape the hash symbol and any others

Lots of options:

```tex
\starttext
\startluacode
    str = "#"

    -- Naïve solution, does not work
    -- context(str)
    -- context.par()

    -- Output in verbatim
    context.verbatim(str)
    context.par()

    -- Backslash escape
    context(str:gsub(str, "\\#"))
    context.par()

    -- \char escape
    context(str:gsub(str, "\\char`\\#"))
    context.par()

    -- ConTeXt escape command
    context(str:gsub(str, "\\letterhash"))
    context.par()

    -- Escape formatter string
    context("%s %!tex! %02X", "test", str, 10)
    context.par()

    -- Manually run the same function
    context(lpeg.match(lpeg.patterns.texescape, str))
    context.par()
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

[image: sample output]